# input value returns when form validation runs false

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, hmvc

**View**

```
<div class="box-body">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="FNAME" class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2">  <span>*</span>First Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FNAME" name="FNAME">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group has-error col-sm-offset-7">
        <label class="control-label" for="error"><?php echo form_error("FNAME"); ?></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function create_id() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('FNAME', 'First Name'         ,'trim|required|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('MNAME', 'Middle Name'            ,'trim|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('SURNAME', 'Last Name'                ,'trim|required|max_length[30]');

    if($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {
        $this->add_view();
    } else {
        if($query = $this->Employees_Model->insert()) {
            $this->autoid();
            redirect('Employees/index');
        } else {
            $this->add_view();
        }
    }   
}
```

What I want is `if($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE){`as you see it will redirect back to view. `$this->add_view();` all I want is when it redirects back, the data that I input will remain. so that I will not input it again when the validation fails.

Comment: This might help you https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per CodeIgniter documentation, you need to alter your view file a little bit, in the means of, printing those input element values with `<?= set_value("FNAME"); ?>` in the input `element _value_ parameter`. So your

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="FNAME" name="FNAME">
```

would become

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="FNAME" name="FNAME" value="<?= set_value("FNAME"); ?>">
```

and so on. This way you will tell CodeIgniter to re-populate the form after an error.

Comment: Yes, but you need a bit more logic, because you need to check which **<option>** needs to be marked as **selected**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [set_value](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#repopulatingform) function.

view file

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="FNAME" name="FNAME" value="<?php echo set_value('FNAME'); ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the posted value like this

```
public function create_id() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('FNAME',      'First Name'            ,'trim|required|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('MNAME',      'Middle Name'           ,'trim|max_length[30]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('SURNAME',    'Last Name'             ,'trim|required|max_length[30]');

    $data = array(
       'FNAME' => $this->input->post('FNAME'),
       'MNAME' => $this->input->post('MNAME'),
       'SURNAME' => $this->input->post('SURNAME')
    );

    if($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE) {
        $this->add_view($data);
    } else {
        if($query = $this->Employees_Model->insert()) {
            $this->autoid();
            redirect('Employees/index');

        } else {
            $this->add_view();
        }
   }
}
```

**In your function**

```
function add_view($data){
    .............................
    .............................
    $this->data['values'] = $data;
    .............................
    .............................

}
```

Then

```
<div class="box-body">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="FNAME" class="col-sm-2 control-label col-sm-offset-2"><span>*</span>First Name:</label>
          <div class="col-sm-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="FNAME" name="FNAME" value="<?= $values['FNAME'] ?>">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-error col-sm-offset-7">
        <label class="control-label" for="error"><?php echo form_error("FNAME"); ?></label>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: i got Message: `Undefined variable: data` on `$this->add_view($data);`